# Win32 CreateThread() Arguments Zero'ed?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, winapi

**Situation**

Up until yesterday, my thread code was working fine. Now though, my thread arguments are being zeroed and moved as they are passed into the thread.

Relevant code in **main.cpp**

```
//First socket: UDP | Second Socket: TCP
std::pair<SOCKET, SOCKET> ServerSockets = Network::Operations::Server();
SOCKET UDPSocket = ServerSockets.first;

//Need to pass two arguments to the thread, when it only accepts one pointer. So create a struct and send the pointer.
ListenData UDPServ;
UDPServ.pNetwork = &Network;
UDPServ.LocalUDPSocket = UDPSocket;
//Set up the listener.
HANDLE UDPListener = Network::Operations::UDPListen(UDPServ);
```

At this stage `UDPSocket` is the correct value (e.g. 103), and `pNetwork` is also correct.

Relevant code in **UDPListen()**

```
    static HANDLE UDPListen(ListenData UDPListenData)
    {
        HANDLE NetworkThread;
        NetworkThread = CreateThread(
            NULL,                           //Default security
            0,                              //Default thread stack size
            Network::Operations::Listen,    //Thread function name
            &UDPListenData,                 //Thread arguments
            0,                              //Default creation flags
            NULL);

        //CloseHandle(NetworkThread);
        return NetworkThread;
    }
```

At this state, the values are as they should be.

Relevant code in **Listen()**

```
    static DWORD WINAPI Listen(void *param)
    {
        ListenData *UDPServ = (ListenData*)param;
        SOCKET Socket = UDPServ->LocalUDPSocket;
        std::vector<Net> *Network = UDPServ->pNetwork;
```

Now however, `UDPSocket` is zero, and `pNetwork` is 103. This is a mystery.

The only code I've really changed is the code to initialise the server, which I modified to incorporate binding a TCP socket. The function used to return a single `SOCKET` but now returns an `std::pair<SOCKET, SOCKET>`.

Comment: I suspect that you should pass  `UDPListenData` by reference:  `static HANDLE UDPListen(ListenData& UDPListenData)`. Currently you seem to be taking the address of a temporary parameter passed by value : `&UDPListenData`

Answer (score 2):

you pass pointer to local data in stack - `&UDPListenData` - but this data is become undefined just after `UDPListen` return. you may be need code like

```
ListenData* UDPServ = new ListenData;
// init UDPServ

HANDLE NetworkThread = CreateThread(
            NULL,                           //Default security
            0,                              //Default thread stack size
            Network::Operations::Listen,    //Thread function name
            UDPServ,                 //Thread arguments
            0,                              //Default creation flags
            NULL);

if (!NetworkThread) delete UDPServ;

//...

static DWORD WINAPI Listen(void *param)
    {
        ListenData *UDPServ = (ListenData*)param;
        SOCKET Socket = UDPServ->LocalUDPSocket;
        std::vector<Net> *Network = UDPServ->pNetwork;
    //...
    delete UDPServ;
}
```

Comment: Still loosing the values :S

Comment: @SyntheticAscension - so still some error in your code, which not visible. but in previous code error definitely in pass temporary object pointer in stack to another thread

Comment: Nevermind got it now, thanks. You were right about about `UDPListen()` returning a value before the other function accesses the values. I declare `UDPServ` in main and then pass the address through.